# Understanding CLIQUE structure

Tags: algorithms, graphs, clique

I am working on the following problem:

Recall the definition of a complete graph Kn is a graph with n vertices such that every vertex
is connected to every other vertex. Recall also that a clique is a complete subset of some graph.
The graph coloring problem consists of assigning a color to each of the vertices of a graph such
that adjacent vertices have different colors and the total number of colors used is minimized. We
define the chromatic number of a graph G to be this minimum number of colors required to color
graph G. Prove that the chromatic number of a graph G is no less than the size of a maximal
clique of G.

So far, I have been thinking about the problem and came up with the following:

- In a clique, every vertex is adjacent to every other vertex
- Therefore, since the problem states adjacent verteces always have different colors, the number of colors needed would be the number of verteces in the clique
- Thus, the chromatic number of any graph G has to be at least the maximal size of the clique, per the definition of a clique.

Can someone verify if my understanding is correct? Or am I glaringly not understanding a clique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is right. So in particular, for any graph $G$ with a clique of size $k$, you will need at least $k$ colors to properly color it. In case this is not obvious, you can think about it via a contradiction. So assume $G$ contains a clique of size $k$, and you have a proper coloring with less than $k$ colors. It follows that the clique contains at least two vertices with the same color. By definition of a clique, these two vertices are adjacent. But this is a contradiction to the coloring being proper.

Further, one might also wonder if the chromatic number of a graph would always equal the clique number. In this direction, you can have a look at [perfect graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph) for which the chromatic number of every induced subgraph equals its clique number. On the other hand, the [Mycielski graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian) show that there are graph that don't even contain a triangle (equivalently, a clique on 3 vertices), while the chromatic number can be arbitrarily large.